# line three button together but space them in three row separately

Tags: android

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="300dp" android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="300dp">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="0.33" android:layout_height="0dp">
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button04" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button05" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button06" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="0.33" android:layout_height="0dp">
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button03" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="0.33" android:layout_height="0dp">
            <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/button3" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Heres my code I want to space those rows I would like to know how can I achieve it?
[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question. It looks like you have it figured out. What would you like differently?

Comment: Trying to put them in the middle instead of the top

Comment: In demos like this, please make the text in each button unique so that we can follow your example visually without having to actually run your code.

Answer (score 0):

On you wrapper LinearLayout add layout_gravity="center_vertical"

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="300dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GridView to get this.

```
    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="15dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `gravity="center"` in main `LinearLayout` like below code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="300dp" android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="300dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```